# RStudio Initialization Error - Unable to connect to server

Tags: r, docker, rstudio

I am trying to start a docker image. The image is supposed to open RStudio when it gets called.
I run the docker image by this command

```
docker run -e PASSWORD=pass --cpus=4 -it --rm -p 8787:8787 hcp4715/rstudio_bayes:cmdstanr
```

And I type

```
http://localhost:8787
```

into my web address.

And I type username : rstudio, password : pass.
But than I get
RStudio Initialization Error - Unable to connect to server

What would be the problem?

Looking at the past post similar to this I tried deleting my
~/.config/rstudio/ and ~/.local/share/rstudio/ file but nothing changes.

The container logs are as below:

```
2023-09-12 10:26:13 [s6-init] making user provided files available at /var/run/s6/etc...exited 0.
2023-09-12 10:26:15 [s6-init] ensuring user provided files have correct perms...exited 0.
2023-09-12 10:26:15 [fix-attrs.d] applying ownership & permissions fixes...
2023-09-12 10:26:15 [fix-attrs.d] done.
2023-09-12 10:26:15 [cont-init.d] executing container initialization scripts...
2023-09-12 10:26:15 [cont-init.d] userconf: executing... 
2023-09-12 10:26:15 [cont-init.d] userconf: exited 0.
2023-09-12 10:26:15 [cont-init.d] done.
2023-09-12 10:26:15 [services.d] starting services
2023-09-12 10:26:15 [services.d] done.
2023-09-12 10:26:26 12 Sep 2023 01:26:26 [rserver] ERROR system error 1 (Operation not permitted); OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::system::posix::{anonymous}::restorePrivilegesImpl(uid_t) src/cpp/shared_core/system/PosixSystem.cpp:66; LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::server::pam_auth::{anonymous}::assumeRootPriv() src/cpp/server/ServerPAMAuth.cpp:57
2023-09-12 10:26:27 12 Sep 2023 01:26:27 [rserver] ERROR system error 1 (Operation not permitted); OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::system::posix::{anonymous}::restorePrivilegesImpl(uid_t) src/cpp/shared_core/system/PosixSystem.cpp:66; LOGGED FROM: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::system::launchChildProcess(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, rstudio::core::system::ProcessConfig, rstudio::core::system::ProcessConfigFilter, PidType*) src/cpp/core/system/PosixSystem.cpp:2107
```

I would appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Can you update the question with the container's log?

Comment: Thank you. I tried clearing my cache but that also didn't work.